# NoReverseMatch during render

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-testing

I'm receiving this error:

> NoReverseMatch at /comments_page/1/post_comment/
>
> Reverse for 'post_comment' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['comments_page/(?P[0-9]+)/post_comment/$']

My views.py

```
def post_comment(request, product_id):
host_product = Product.objects.get(pk=product_id)
comment = Comment()
comment.product = host_product
comment.author = request.POST["author"]
comment.comment_text = request.POST["comment"]
comment.save()
return render(request, 'comments_page/detail.html', {"host_product": host_product})
```

My comments_page\urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = "comments_page"

urlpatterns = [
    # /comments_page/
    url(r'^$', views.index, name="index"),

    # /comments_page/1/
    url(r'^(?P<product_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name="detail"),

    # /comments_page/1/post_comment/
    url(r'^(?P<product_id>[0-9]+)/post_comment/$', views.post_comment, name='post_comment'),]
```

My detail.html

```
<form action="{% url 'comments_page:post_comment' product.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    Name: <input type="text" id="author" name="author">

    Comment:
    <textarea id="comment" name="comment"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Post Comment">
```

I think I've identified the problem as being in the product.id here

```
{% url 'comments_page:post_comment' product.id %}
```

in the html page. I've tried formatting this a couple of different ways, but I haven't had any luck. Do note, the comment is going through and the form and it works as far as updating the database and loading the entry on the page goes, but the page is not being redirected. I have to reload it manually. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `{% url 'comments_page:post_comment' product_id=host_product.id %}`!

Comment: This redirects the user to a page without any database information pulled in, similar to knbk's suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message shows that the argument you pass to the `{% url %}` tag does not exist and resolves to an empty string. Your view indeed does not pass in a `product` variable, only a `host_product` variable. You need to change the tag accordingly:

```
{% url 'comments_page:post_comment' host_product.id %}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it stops the error, but it redirects the user to a generic page without any database information pulled in. I found a solution myself by changing the context to  {"product": host_product}. I'm not sure why this works.

I feel I may be over complicating things by saving the object's id in host_products. Somewhere along the way, I'm losing my understanding of where id's are being passed or where objects are being identified.

Comment: @brno32 That's fine, you can call it `product` or `host_product`, that doesn't matter. The only thing that matters is that you use the name you choose consistently. Apparently you were using the name `product` elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

For those who may wonder, the fix is to change the return function in views.py to this

```
return render(request, 'comments_page/detail.html', {"product": host_product})
```

I do not understand why this works, but it does. Any suggestions as to how to clean up my post_comment function would be appreciated. I feel it's overly convoluted by using host_product